# Can't open python script in macOS app package with double-click

Tags: python, macos, desktop-application

I have an ".app" bundle with python script in its `Contents/MacOS/` and I can open it (and it works properly) using `open AppName.app` command in Terminal.

But if I double-click it to open it, its icon appears in dock for a fraction of a second, and disappears.

Comment: Can you give more information? What framework did you use to write the app? Does anything special happen at startup, etc.

Comment: @mprat no frameworks. Manually created app bundle. It just runs python script in its `Contents/MacOS/` and it works if I open an app using `open AppName.app` command in Terminal.